# issues in converting images in doc file to PDF

Tags: microsoft-word

We have received word files from the author as in [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-sIaOq-w834eHN5Q25RbExBdkE/view?usp=sharing)

While converting the image to PDF using Adobe PDF/Acrobat Distiller, the image becomes distorted:

[image]

The lines in the graph are misplaced. What might be the reason for this how can I get the exact output in a PDF?

Comment: A couple questions.  What are you using to do the conversion and what version exactly??  What versions of Adobe Acrobat does the has its compatibility set to?    Please update your question to include this information.

Comment: What happens if you save to pdf from word (File > Export > Create PDF/XPS.)?

Comment: I'd suggest to try the [online converter](http://www.zamzar.com/) and see if it keeps the format untouched.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert word to pdf by using Microsoft Office add-in http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=9943

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you'll want to find the original Excel file, then extract the graph from there as an unlinked object or complete image. In the Word file you provided, the graph is still linked to the data, which is embedded.

I was able to just open the .docx file in Acrobat (XI Pro) without any of the distortion (screenshot below). You can find that PDF [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YMffSrvjNTamVjbHV3eFZ0bDg/view?usp=sharing).

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. There is no issue in creating PDF directly from Ms-Word using 'MS-word->Acrobat menu->Create pdf'. The problem is while creating WORD-PRN-PDF. This is the workflow we follow.